# Data in templates

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-orm

I need your support.
I have 2 models Author and Post, I want to display the data for a particular author in a template. I want display the posts of an specific Author, and the information (first_name and last_name) of that Author. In my view file I created a method, with 2 querysets. One of this QuerySet looks in the table Post the posts of an specific Author, and the other query set looks in the Author table the information of the Author owner of the posts.

My question, Can I do this with only one QuerySet? If yes, How can I display it in the template?

MODELS

```
class Autor(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, verbose_name='First Name')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, verbose_name='Last Name')

class Post(models.Model):
    autor = models.ForeignKey(Autor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, verbose_name='Post')
```

VIEW.PY

```
def index(request):
    autor = Autor.objects.filter(first_name='Peter').first()
    autor_posts = Post.objects.filter(autor__first_name='Peter')
    return render(request, 'posts.html', {'autor_posts': autor_posts, 'autor': autor})
```

POSTS.HTML

```
Author: {{ autor.first_name }}, {{ autor.last_name }}


Posts:
{% for post in autor_posts %}
    <p>{{ post.id }}, {{ post.post }}</p>
    <p></p>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with:

```py
def index(request):
    autor = Autor.objects.prefetch_related('post_set').filter(first_name='Peter').first()
    return render(request, 'posts.html', {'autor': autor})
```

This will still do two queries though, one to get the `autor` and one to  prefetch all the related `post` of the `autor`. But the advantage is you don't have to manually write a separate filter to get the `autor`'s posts.

So in your template you can do this:

```
Author: {{ autor.first_name }}, {{ autor.last_name }}

Posts:
{% for post in autor.post_set.all %}
    <p>{{ post.id }}, {{ post.post }}</p>
    <p></p>
{% endfor %}
```